# pub get does not install redstone package

Tags: dart, dart-pub, redstone.dart

I have an issue with pub. I'm new in dart. I followed the instructions on the redstone web page (http://redstonedart.org/doc/Installation.html) to use redstone in my server project.

I'm using webstorm. here is a copy-paste of my **pubspec.yaml** :

```
name: ndolo_server

dependencies:
redstone: any
```

when I run *pub get* on the application root folder or on webstorm, pub seem to work correctly (it displays "Got dependencies") but the package folder stay empty.
I ran cache repair (*pub cache repair*), here also it seems to work correctly, but the package folder stay empty.

when I run pub get --trace, I get the following output :

```
E:\devel\webapps\ndolo2\server> pub get --trace
Resolving dependencies...
Got dependencies!
E:\devel\webapps\ndolo2\server>
```

Can someone help me?

thank!

Comment: Might be a similar issue like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537227/cannot-add-mdl-packages-to-pub-cache

Comment: Can you please try `pub get --trace` from command line from your project directory and add the output to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a space or a tab before `redstone...`.
See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec.html for more details.