# Cannot add mdl packages to pub cache

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I cannot add the package mdl https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl
to pub cache using either the

`command pub cache add mdl`

or using the dependency

```
dependencies:
  mdl: "^1.1.2"
```

in my pubspec.yaml file.

The author says it is a Windows issue as it works as designed on Linux and iOS.

I am using the current WebStorm on Windows 8.1 x64. This is the first time I am having such an issue.

Using the command line

```
pub --trace cache add mdl
```

I receive the following trace

```
    J:\workspace\epimss\dart\epimss_app>pub --trace cache add mdl
Downloading mdl 1.1.2...
Timed out after 30.0s while downloading https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl/versions/1.1.2.tar.gz.
This is likely a transient error. Please try again later.
package:pub/src/io.dart 859                timeout.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                 Timer.Timer
package:pub/src/io.dart 848                timeout
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 194     HostedSource._download.<fn>.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                 _Future.then
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 193     HostedSource._download.<fn>
dart:async                                 Future.Future.sync
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 184     HostedSource._download
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 93      HostedSource.downloadToSystemCache.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                 _Future.then
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 86      HostedSource.downloadToSystemCache
package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 81  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>.downloadVersion.<async>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                 _Future.then
package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 73  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>.downloadVersion.<async>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub                                CacheAddCommand.run.<async>.downloadVersion
package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 91  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                 _Future.then
package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 62  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                 Future.Future.microtask
package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart     CacheAddCommand.run
package:args/command_runner.dart 178       CommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
dart:async                                 Future.Future.sync
package:args/command_runner.dart 131       CommandRunner.runCommand
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 122    PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>.<fn>
dart:async                                 Future.Future.sync
package:pub/src/utils.dart 103             captureErrors.<fn>
package:stack_trace                        Chain.capture
package:pub/src/utils.dart 117             captureErrors
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 122    PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>
---- Log transcript ----
FINE: Pub 1.12.0-dev.3.1
IO  : Spawning "cmd /c ver" in J:\workspace\epimss\dart\epimss_app\.
IO  : Finished ver. Exit code 0.
    | stdout:
    | |
    | | Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
    | Nothing output on stderr.
IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/mdl.
FINE: HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/mdl
    | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.12.0-dev.3.1
FINE: HTTP response 200 OK for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/mdl
    | took 0:00:00.418239
    | cache-control: private
    | transfer-encoding: chunked
    | accept-ranges: none
    | date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 10:46:10 GMT
    | vary: Accept-Encoding
    | content-type: application/json
    | x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    | via: infb126:25935
    | x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    | x-content-type-options: nosniff
    | server: Google Frontend
IO  : Get package from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl/versions/1.1.2.tar.gz.
MSG : Downloading mdl 1.1.2...
IO  : Created temp directory C:\Users\st.clair.clarke\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\_temp\dirb0c89391-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb
FINE: HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl/versions/1.1.2.tar.gz
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.12.0-dev.3.1
FINE: HTTP response 200 OK for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl/versions/1.1.2.tar.gz
    | took 0:00:00.535308
    | x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
    | last-modified: Mon, 20 Jul 2015 21:01:24 GMT
    | cache-control: public, max-age=3600
    | date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 10:46:10 GMT
    | vary: Accept-Encoding
    | x-goog-stored-content-length: 32419840
    | x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2UrdnbZJiDQihBiYH0s_eE3L2Q7ZmBDJJtJYZsQZFxtFlqWfruJmKw6OcdIxPVkru0t5vCVii9thOYsI0NLfl7O19rS9rA
    | x-goog-hash: crc32c=QJe0BQ==,md5=u5fMJcctgRWlUW3ycRmg2A==
    | content-type: application/octet-stream
    | x-goog-generation: 1437426084774000
    | server: UploadServer
    | alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=1
    | accept-ranges: bytes
    | content-length: 32419840
    | x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
    | etag: "bb97cc25c72d8115a5516df27119a0d8"
    | x-goog-metageneration: 2
    | expires: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 11:46:10 GMT
FINE: Extracting .tar.gz stream to C:\Users\st.clair.clarke\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\_temp\dirb0c89391-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb.
IO  : Created temp directory C:\Users\STCLAI~1.CLA\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b0c89392-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb
IO  : Creating C:\Users\STCLAI~1.CLA\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b0c89392-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb\data.tar.gz from stream.
FINE: Created C:\Users\STCLAI~1.CLA\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b0c89392-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb\data.tar.gz from stream.
IO  : Spawning "J:\dart\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe e data.tar.gz" in C:\Users\STCLAI~1.CLA\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b0c89392-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb
IO  : Finished J:\dart\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe. Exit code 0.
    | stdout:
    | |
    | | 7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
    | |
    | | Processing archive: data.tar.gz
    | |
    | | Extracting  data.tar
    | |
    | | Everything is Ok
    | |
    | | Size:       44359680
    | | Compressed: 32419840
    | Nothing output on stderr.
IO  : Spawning "J:\dart\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x C:\Users\STCLAI~1.CLA\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b0c89392-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ffb\data.tar" in C:\Users\st.clair.clarke\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\_temp\dirb0c89391-2f95-11e5-80a7-3085a98f2ff
b
ERR : Timed out after 30.0s while downloading https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl/versions/1.1.2.tar.gz.
    | This is likely a transient error. Please try again later.
FINE: Exception type: TimeoutException
ERR : package:pub/src/io.dart 859                timeout.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                 Timer.Timer
    | package:pub/src/io.dart 848                timeout
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 194     HostedSource._download.<fn>.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                 _Future.then
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 193     HostedSource._download.<fn>
    | dart:async                                 Future.Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 184     HostedSource._download
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 93      HostedSource.downloadToSystemCache.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                 _Future.then
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 86      HostedSource.downloadToSystemCache
    | package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 81  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>.downloadVersion.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                 _Future.then
    | package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 73  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>.downloadVersion.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | package:pub                                CacheAddCommand.run.<async>.downloadVersion
    | package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 91  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                 _Future.then
    | package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart 62  CacheAddCommand.run.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                 Future.Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/command/cache_add.dart     CacheAddCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 178       CommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                 Future.Future.sync
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 131       CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 122    PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>.<fn>
    | dart:async                                 Future.Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 103             captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                        Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 117             captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 122    PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>
---- End log transcript ----
```

Comment: I have seen similar issues several times. AFAIR it starts working again by itself after a while (next day). I have no idea what causes it.

Comment: I have been trying this now for about two weeks with the same result. I even contacted the author and was advised as stated above. Do you think it is a bug?

Comment: Maybe a network issue. Very probably nothing caused by the author. Either on your side or on the side of pub.dartlang.org.

Comment: Hardly likely. I tried it both at home and at work on two different computers with the same result.

Comment: I would create a bug report in https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart. Please cross-link the issue and this SO question after you created the issue.

Comment: same thing happening here, under Linux.